# Is there any testnet for trading? I want to test trading my newly created token

Tags: blockchain, solidity, decentralized-applications

I'm a newbie here. We are currently developing a token but we need to test it as if we are trading on mainnet. Is there any testnet for trading on BSC testnet? Our token is now registered on testnet in bscscan. I also set the liquidity for my test token.

Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Use Rinkeby testnet and Uniswap. Uniswap and Pancakeswap have the same codes so if it works with Uniswap, it should work with Pancakeswap

Comment: What for like margin trading?